# Error while saving a time value from select filed in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a form with this select:

```
<select id="time">
  <option value="00:00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:50:00">00:50</option>
  <option value="02:00:00">02:00</option>
 </select>
```

And i use php+mysql to store/update selected value for this form. For some reason i get an error while saving, and i see that the query is (for example, for update):

```
UPDATE assistentprezzo_b SET time_to = '00::5:00', param = 0, type = 1, value = 1200.00 WHERE id = 1
```

So for some reason system transforms "00:50:00" to strange "00::5:00". Why it happens? The type of field in db is "TIME", by the way...

UPDATE: unfortunately, i cannot see the part of code that provides storing/updating this value, because it a job of scriptcase tool - it is a php code generator...But i can change the format of time variable in select and i have access to db with phpMyAdmin, so i can also change type of field in table

Comment: Can we get the part of your code that handles the form data and constructs SQL query?

Comment: It was an expected question. Unfortunately, this part of action is passed by scriptcase (rapid php development tool - code generator), so i can't see what is inside... And if the problem is not with format of time or settings of sql field in a table, i do not know what to do

Answer (score 0):

So finally i changed format in select options from "00:00:00" to "00.00.00" and it works well. If any person, that uses scriptcase, will someday google this problem and find my answer - you are lucky man!